# It is not necessary that every headache has to be tumor

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I think this not a right sentence. Can anyone help me to correct this?

Comment: It seems like valid syntax and semantics to me.  A little awkward, perhaps, and not particularly idiomatic.

Comment: Aside from a missing article in front of *tumour*, there's nothing wrong with that sentence. Versions that might be a bit more idiomatically are: (1) *it's not (the case / necessarily true) that every headache is caused by a tumour*; and (2) *it's not (the case / necessarily true) that a tumour causes every headache.*

Comment: Just like other adjectives expressing necessity or obligation, "necessary" calls for subjunctive: *It is not necessary that every headache **be** a tumor*. Alternatively, the pattern "for sth/sb to V-inf" can be used: *It is not necessary for every headache to be a tumor*.

Comment: "Every headache doesn't have to be a tumor." -or- "Every headache isn't necessarily a tumor."

Comment: @Gustavson WTG! You could post that as an answer because an answer is what it is. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the sentence as close to the original as possible you would at least need to add an article in front of the word "tumor." 
This would give you "a tumor" or "the tumor."
To write it in a more natural way I might say "A headache does not necessarily mean there is a tumor" or "Not every headache means there is a tumor."

Comment: Or, "The headache is more likely to be caused by a stroke, but it *could* be a tumor."

Comment: That works too!

Comment: -1 See comment by Gustavson @OP.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the grammar of the sentence and leaving aside other ways in which it could be more accurately expressed, the truth is that, just like other adjectives expressing necessity or obligation, "necessary" calls for the subjunctive mood:

- It is not necessary that every headache **be** a tumor.

Alternatively, the pattern "for sth/sb to V-inf" can be used:

- It is not necessary **for every headache to be** a tumor.